# how to create Log entry once button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have a android widget which is managed by a service. In the `onStartCommand` I do:

```
for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
            .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
            R.layout.main);         

    // Register an onClickListener
    Intent clickIntent = CreateWifiSettingsIntent(this.getApplicationContext());

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

    Log.i(LOG, "onClickListener Registered");
    }
```

`CreateWifiSettingsIntent` is doing simply constructing a PendingIntent:

```
public Intent CreateWifiSettingsIntent(Context context) {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");

    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    /* this Log will be called whenever the intent is created */
    Log.i(LOG, "Intent created: com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");

    return intent;

}
```

What I would like to do, is to add a `Log.i()` call which will be executed every time that a user presses the button. I there a way that I can add this here?

Comment: Why is it not possible to add the Log.i() call in the onclick method of the onClickListener of your button?

Comment: @Flav Ideally I want the original Intent to get executed (wifi settings) PLUS I want `Log.i` to be called. I just don't know how to combine these two. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can we show your main.xml???

Comment: @DhawalSodha this problem has nothing to do with main.xml